# How to make a dynamic PDF viewer in isolated page? SharePoint 365

Tags: sharepoint-online, hyperlink, pdf

I need to make a page for my company where we will show the daily report. The page must be updated daily and maintain the same access link. In the page we want to show a PDF through a PDF viewer. The page will be accessible for people outside of my company, and must not have pathways to other pages, I think I can control that through permissions and not showing links.

How can I do this in SharePoint?
Do you have any sugestions?

Comment: can you confirm a couple things:  1.  Do you have external guest access enabled on your tenant & are you regularly auditing for any sharing links that would permit guest access to any other content?  (Anonymous, external access is a tenant-wide setting in SharePoint.) 2. Will the page have a built-in pdf viewer webpart?  SharePoint online does not handle PDFs like the on-prep version.  On-prem you could add the PDF mime type to be viewable within the Word web app.  That’s not really the case in SharePoint online.  3. Do you actually have to host the PDF file on a page?

Comment: @A.k.A.Fritz   1. I don't have external access enabled because the website is closed, but this specific page will be open and with no access to other parts of the site. 2. I think it's a good solution, but I want to find other options as well. 3. I'm talking with my supervisor about using the site itself as the report instead of a PDF file, but the PDF is the best solution so far.